# How can I deserialize Array inside of Array google-gson

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

I have JSON like that:

```
{
 "Answers":
 [
  [
   {"Locale":"Ru","Name":"Name1"},
   {"Locale":"En","Name":"Name2"}
  ],
  [
   {"Locale":"Ru","Name":"Name3"},
   {"Locale":"En","Name":"Name4"}
  ]
 ]
}
```

As you can see, I have array inside of array. How can I deserialize such JSON structure into an object using **google-gson** library on Android (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Comment: Please read the `gson` tag wiki.  There is no need for `google-gson`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Json format we got something like this:

**MyObject**

```
public class MyObject {
public List<List<Part>> Answers;

public List<List<Part>> getAnswers() {
    return Answers;
  }
}
```

**Part**

```
public class Part {
private String Locale;
private String Name;

public String getLocale() {
    return Locale;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "    {" + 
            "       \"Answers\": [[{" + 
            "           \"Locale\": \"Ru\"," + 
            "           \"Name\": \"Name1\"" + 
            "       }," + 
            "       {" + 
            "           \"Locale\": \"En\"," + 
            "           \"Name\": \"Name2\"" + 
            "       }]," + 
            "       [{" + 
            "           \"Locale\": \"Ru\"," + 
            "           \"Name\": \"Name3\"" + 
            "       }," + 
            "       {" + 
            "           \"Locale\": \"En\"," + 
            "           \"Name\": \"Name4\"" + 
            "       }]]" + 
            "    }";

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    MyObject obj  = gson.fromJson(str, MyObject.class);

    List<List<Part>> answers = obj.getAnswers();

    for(List<Part> parts : answers){
        for(Part part : parts){
            System.out.println("locale: " + part.getLocale() + "; name: " + part.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
locale: Ru; name: Name1
locale: En; name: Name2
locale: Ru; name: Name3
locale: En; name: Name4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
public class MyObject extends ArrayList<ArrayList<Part>>
{
     public List<Part> Answers
}
```

Also use can deserialize this by using the given code

```
 List<Part> Answers = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class));
```

Hope this will help you..