# How to Parse this Json using Gson and get the field I want?

Tags: json, gson

```
{
"ws_result": 
[
    {
        "token": "", 
    "norm_token": "",
        "len": "", 
        "type": "", 
        "pos": "", 
        "prop": "", 
        "stag": "", 
        "child": 
    [
            {
                "token": "", 
"norm_token":"",
                "len": "", 
                "type": "", 
                "pos": "", 
                "prop": "", 
                "stag": "", 
                "child": 
[
                    {
                        "token": "", 
                                  "norm_token":"",
                        "len": "", 
                        "type": "", 
                        "pos": "", 
                        "prop": "", 
                        "stag": "", 
                        "child": [ ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "token": "", 
                                 "norm_token":"",
                        "len": "", 
                        "type": "", 
                        "pos": "", 
                        "prop": "", 
                        "stag": "", 
                        "child": [ ]
                    }                   
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "token": "", 
        "norm_token":"", 
                "len": "", 
                "type": "", 
                "pos": "", 
                "prop": "", 
                "stag": "", 
                "child": 
[
                    {
                        "token": "", 
"norm_token":"",
                        "len": "", 
                        "type": "", 
                        "pos": "", 
                        "prop": "", 
                        "stag": "", 
                        "child": [ ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "token": "", 
            "norm_token":"",
        "len": "", 
        "type": "", 
        "pos": "", 
        "prop": "", 
        "stag": "2", 
        "child": [ ]
    }, 
    {
        "token": "", 
            "norm_token": "",
        "len": "", 
        "type": "", 
        "pos": "", 
        "prop": "", 
        "stag": "", 
        "child": [ ]
    }
]
}
```

Such that some children are empty some is not, and some children contain more children. How do I actually parse this thing and get what I want. I am totally new with Json, and I am trying to use Gson. What I want is to get a value of a token with specific type in the nested Json. Thanks a lot for any help and directions.

I tried use com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader, but ist not working

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(result));
      jsonReader.beginObject();
      while(jsonReader.hasNext()){
           String field = jsonReader.nextName();
            if (field.equals("type")){
                System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
            } else if (field.equals("token")){
                System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
            } else {
         jsonReader.skipValue();
        }


        }
        jsonReader.endObject();
```

Comment: I have tried the following
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(result));
          jsonReader.beginObject();
            while(jsonReader.hasNext()){
                String field = jsonReader.nextName();
                if (field.equals("ws_result")){
                    System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
                } else if (field.equals("granu_type")){
                    System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
                } else {
                    jsonReader.skipValue();
                }


            }
            jsonReader.endObject();

Comment: I just need some Ideas, and how to handle nested json, what are the ways. I tried gson.stream.jsonreader

Comment: post code in the question, also the json you posted is invalid.

Comment: how is this Json invalid?

Comment: it's not closed properly.  Also, have you checked for existing question/answers for this issue?  You can't be the first person to need to parse nested json structures with gson.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing nested JSON data using GSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169754/parsing-nested-json-data-using-gson)

Comment: you can use this to view the Json, it is closed properly: http://json.parser.online.fr/
Also, my Json is nested with children, and that is not nested
Can you also stop voting down my question? I really need to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your json recursively like this:

http://snipplr.com/view/71742/java-reflection-and-recursive-json-deserializer-using-gson/

```
private void parse(JsonObject o, PackagingResponse r){
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonElement>> i = o.entrySet().iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            Entry<String, JsonElement> e = i.next();
            JsonElement el = e.getValue();
            if(el.isJsonObject())
                parse(el.getAsJsonObject(), r);
            //......
        }
    }
```

Comment: Appreciated, i will try this method and let you know how it goes tmr!! thanks a lot for your help and direction.