# How to change values Json

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson, objectmapper

I read json

```
{
  "id"   : 1,
  "name" : {
    "first" : "Yong",
    "last" : "Mook Kim"
  },
  "contact" : [
    { "type" : "phone/home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"},
    { "type" : "phone/work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}
  ]
}
```

by ObjectMapper

```
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(JsonNodeTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.json"), Map.class);
```

value type may be

```
Map<String,Object>
```

also having

```
Map<String, Object> replaceValues = new HashMap<>();
replaceValues.put("id", "2")
replaceValues.put("first", "Yong");
```

how to change recursively change values in jsonMap?

Comment: Create a proper class instead of using a map.

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively change values"?  Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Unclear why this as marked as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169754/parsing-nested-json-data-using-gson - this is evidently a question about Jackson.